# Avoid anonymous function in Mootools?

Tags: javascript, events, mootools, anonymous-function

Here's my problem: I'm looking for a way to work with 'not anonymous' function in Mootools. 
Can't find a way to work it out, and I couldn't find doc about it.

**Example:** 
`var myInput = new Element('input', {
        type: 'text',
        value: 'hello world',
        events: {blur: function(){ .... }
        };
    });`

**OR**
`$$('td[title]').addEvents('dblclick':function(){...});`

**AND a Simple function** 
`function sayHello(){alert('hello')}`

What should I do if I want onBlur/ondblClick event calls an existing function (eg. sayHello) ? I know I could call my existing function inside the anonymous one, but is there any better/suitable way to do that call ? 
I'm stuck on that problem for a few days, maybe it's quite simple, but I simply can't figure it out.

Thank you.

EDIT : 
How could I missed that ??? Thank you guys for the help, worked great !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions are first class citizens in Javascript, so you can reference them like this:

```
$$('td[title]').addEvents('dblclick':sayHello);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$$('td[title]').addEvents({'dblclick':sayHello});
```

because a function is a variable, you can use it as you would use a variable, in this case as a value of a hash

also i should point out that both of these functions will have the same name:

```
function sayHello(){}

and

var sayHello = function(){}
```

they both make a function called 'sayHello' (with subtle differences that you dont care about right now)

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass in a reference to your function directly, as if it were any other variable:

```
var myInput = new Element('input', {
    type: 'text',
    value: 'hello world',
    events: {blur: sayHello}
});
```